# Hacky or Trick ways of creating a custom dir input item on Select Destination Location wizard page

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create a Portable Installer that will put my installation files directly into the " Root of my USB pen drive ( eg. F:\  ) ". As I know by default inno-setup does not allow to put installation files directly into the Root of the Hard Drive (eg. C:\  ) or into the Root of USB pen Drive (eg. F:\  ), instead it will command you to add a Directory manually in order to put installation files over there,  or it will create it by default for you ( eg. C:\ MyPro , or  F:\ MyPro) depending on your settings ( [ DefaultDirName={pf}\MyPro ] ).
So due to this behaviour I would like to know " The Hacky or Trick ways of creating a custom dir input item on Select Destination Location wizard page " so that It produces slightly different browse for folder dialog that will solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: Installing on root should be avoided!**

Set these directives in the `[Setup]` section of your script:

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=no
DefaultDirName=c:\
DirExistsWarning=no
AllowRootDirectory=yes
AppendDefaultDirName=no
```